# embed external website in html5

Tags: html, embed, responsive

I have two websites and want to embed one website into another website. For this I'm using embed code

```
<object data="http://mywebsite.com" width="100%" height="100%">
      <embed src="http://mywebsite.com" width="100%" height="100%"> </embed>
      Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
    </object>
```

to make it full screen ie., height and width to 100% have CSS properties set to

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Now, `http://mywebsite.com/` is responsive but embedding this website is not responsive and is showing zoomed out desktop version.

What I have to do is to make it behave like as it behave when browsed through `http://mywebsite.com/`

Comment: Why not try using an iframe instead?

Comment: iframe is not supported in html5

Comment: Are you sure you know HTML5 ? iframes are still supported with few attributes deprecated.https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question but something about an unanswered question bothers my OCD! So I am adding this to help future users.

Try changing CSS  `min-height: 100%; to min-height: 110vh;`